# Set Value to x if Value is empty JQUERY Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, parameters

```
function filterShips() {
    if ( $("#torso").val() == "" ) {
        $("#torso").val("-1");
    }
    if ( $("#race").val() == "" ) {
        $("#race").val("-1");
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/filter.php",
        async: false,
        data: "t="+$("#torso").val()+"&r="+$("#race").val()
    });
}
```

If the Value is empty it should be set to -1 but this seems not to work FireBug shows me

> GET ajax/filter.php?t=undefined&r=undefined

```
<select name="torso" id="torso" onchange="filterShips();">
<option value="-1">alle</option>
<option value="0">torso 1</option>
<option value="1">torso 2</option>
<option value="2">torso 3</option>
<option value="3">torso 4</option>
<option value="4">torso 5</option>
<option value="5">torso 6</option>
<option value="6">torso 7</option>
<option value="7">torso 8</option>
<option value="8">torso 9</option>
<option value="9">torso 10</option>
<option value="10">torso 11</option>
<option value="11">torso 12</option>
<option value="12">torso 13</option>
<option value="13">torso 14</option>
<option value="14">torso 15</option>
</select>

<select name="race" id="race" onchange="filterShips();">
<option value="-1">alle</option>
<option value="0">r1</option>
<option value="1">r2</option>
<option value="2">r3</option>
</select>
```

If i make a selection the transmittet parameters are correct!

Comment: can you post relevant HTML code?

Comment: What element is torso? What element is race? Post your HTML

Comment: if #torso and #race is not input element, use $("#...").text() or $("#...").html()

Comment: i added the specific HTML Code

Comment: It says in the URL that `$("#race").val()` is `undefined` - but you're checking it against a blank string. (`"" != undefined`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your function to:

```
function filterShips() {
    var torso = $("#torso").val(); //or "#torso option:selected"
    var race = $("#race").val();
    if ( !torso ) {
        torso = '-1';
    }
    if (!race) {
        race = '-1';
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/filter.php",
        async: false,
        data: "t="+torso+"&r="+race
    });
}
```

Comment: It vorked! But not val torso or val race i'ved to use "var"

Comment: @TheMasta oh yes that was typo

Answer (score 0):

what are torso and race in your page? Are they textboxes? Try inserting some variables:

```
function filterShips()
{
    var torso = "";
    var race = "";
    if($("#torso").val() == ""){
      torso = "-1";
    }
    else {
      torso = $('#torso').val(); 
    }

    if($("#race").val() == ""){
      race = "-1";
    }
    else { 
      race = $('#race').val();
    }
     $.ajax({

          type: "GET",
          url: "ajax/filter.php",
          async: false,
          data: "t="+ torso+"&r="+race

      });
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use variables, there's no point fetching `val()` twice - just default the variables to the element's `.val()`, then reset to -1 if necessary. That way there's no need to fetch the element's value twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
function filterShips() {
    var torso = $("#torso").val();
    var race = $("#race").val();

    if ( !$.trim(torso).length || typeof torso === "undefined") {
        torso = -1;
    }
    if ( !$.trim(race).length || typeof race === "undefined") {
        race = -1;
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ajax/filter.php",
        async: false,
        data: "t="+torso+"&r="+race
    });
}
```